# Error obj.javaClass.`package` when running tests after corda upgrade

Tags: java, unit-testing, corda

I just upgraded from corda 3.3 to 4.0 and then all my contract and flow tests started to fail. these are failing in those lines where I'm defining transactions (transaction builder objects, when adding oputput and input satates).

```
ledger(ledgerServices, l -> {
    l.transaction(tx -> {
        tx.input(fooContract.foo_CONTRACT_ID, fooContractState);
        tx.command(Arrays.asList(node1.getPublicKey(),   
                   node2.getPublicKey()), 
                   new fooContract.Commands.dummyCommand()); 
        // Correct type.
        return tx.verifies();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> obj.javaClass.`package` must not be null

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem caused when a TransactionBuilder was trying to find a StatePointer inside the transaction and a package name was null (The logical to find a package was wrong, because It was considering and calling something that was null in its origin). Remindering you that StatePointer was released only Corda Platform Open Source 4.0.
I recommend you upgrade your CorDapp to the version Corda 4.1 because it was fixed on March 7, 2019 and released only in Corda 4.1.

Your log should be logging something like this:

obj.javaClass.`package` must not be null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: obj.javaClass.`package` must not be null
at net.corda.core.internal.StatePointerSearch.handleObject(StatePointerSearch.kt:75)
at net.corda.core.internal.StatePointerSearch.handleField(StatePointerSearch.kt:85)
at net.corda.core.internal.StatePointerSearch.search(StatePointerSearch.kt:92)
at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.resolveStatePointers(TransactionBuilder.kt:494)
at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addOutputState(TransactionBuilder.kt:568)

For more information:
https://github.com/corda/corda/commits/release/4.1/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/internal/StatePointerSearch.kt

Looking at commit realized on Mar 7, 2019, the handleObject(obj: Any?) method was trying to get an attribute called 'name' in packageName attribute, but the 'name' atributte is null.